# Symbol read twice from ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I found a strange behavior with std::ifstream (or more probably I'm missing something on how to properly use it). I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        std::ifstream file;
        file.open(argv[1]);

        while(not file.eof()) {
                int x;
                file >> x;
                std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I call it on a file that contains numbers separated by spaces, like the following:

```
1 34 567 3
```

The program outputs:

```
1
34
567
3
3
```

The last number is always duplicated. I guess it's because it does not reach EOF after reading the last number, it reaches the mandatory '\n' of text files, and the next file >> x gives me again the last read number.

How can I properly detect that there is no more number to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
int x;
    while(file >> x;) {  
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
      }
```

For better understanding [Please go through this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/3110262)

Hope this will help you.